# Incrementing an implicitly unwrapped optional

Tags: swift, option-type

I declare an implicitly unwrapped optional as:

```
var numberOfRows: Int!
```

and initialize it in init:

```
numberOfRows = 25
```

Later I need to decrement it by one so I write:

```
numberOfRows--
```

but this doesn't compile. The error message says the decrement operator can't be applied to an implicitly unwrapped optional. With a little experimentation I find that the following compiles without error:

```
numberOfRows!--
```

I would like to understand this. What is the explanation for what seems like the extra '!'?

Comment: Why not just skip the optional and initialize your int to something, e.g. `var numberOfRows:Int = 0`? An explicitly unwrapped optional is still an optional.

Comment: That's just how the language works. If it really bothers you, then write `numberOfRows = numberOfRows - 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Implicitly unwrapped optional* is a type on its own, and is different from the type it that wraps.  Some operators on *optionals* and *implicitly unwrapped optionals* are pre-defined for you out of the box by the language, but for the rest you have to define them yourself.

In this particular case an operator `postfix func --(inout value: Int!) -> Int!` is just not defined.  If you want to use postfix `--` operator on `Int!` just the same way you use it on `Int` then you will have to define one.

E.g. something like:

```
postfix func --<T: SignedIntegerType>(inout value: T!) -> T! {
    guard let _value = value else { return nil }

    value = _value - 1
    return _value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we look at what the `optional` type is, we will see that this is `enum` like:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case Some(T)
    case None
}
```

And it can be `Some Type` like `Int` for example or `None` and in this case it's have `nil` value.

When you make this:

```
var numberOfRows: Int!
```

you directly is indicated by the `!` that this is not `Int` type but this is the `enum Optional<Int>` type. At moment of creation it's will be `Some<Int>` if equal it value but with this `!` you have that it is `enum Optional<Int>` and in some next moment it will be the `None`. That's why you have to use `!` second time when make this:

```
numberOfRows!--
```

Your `nomberOfRows` value is `Optional<Int>` type and it may be `Int` or `nil` and  you have to directly indicate that this is `Int` type to make `--` action.