# Why '+=' does not work for implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Tags: swift, option-type

When updating the text of UITextView, I found `textView.text += "..."` does not work. The compiler warned me that "Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String!' and 'String'". It seems that I must append an exclamatory mark after `textView.text`.

However, if I expanded it to `textView.text = textView.text + "..."`, it worked. I wonder whether it is designed as this or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Essentially the same issue as in [Incrementing an implicitly unwrapped optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33504945/incrementing-an-implicitly-unwrapped-optional).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicitly unwrapped optional is still an `Optional` and it's different from type that it wraps. So you need to define operator:

```
func +=(inout l: String!, r: String) {
    l = (l ?? "") + r
}

var a: String! = "a"
var b: String = "b"

a += b // "ab"
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are different, when u are doing textField.text+="text" , means u are adding another string on it. But when u are using textField.text = textField.text + "text", means u are adding 2 string and setting into textField.